# Can opening hours schema markup be used with the markup for local businesses or libraries?

Tags: microdata, local-seo

Can the OpeningHours mark-up visible [in this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50368/schema-or-data-vocabulary-microdata-for-breadcrumbs) for  `schema.org/Store` (example 2) with microdata be used in conjunction with `schema.org/LocalBusiness` or `schema.org/Library`?

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters.  I have heavily edited your question so that it can remain open on this site.   We only allow one question per post.   I have chosen one of your two questions for this post.  You are welcome to ask the other one as a new question in a second posting.

Comment: user41760, which question containing "example 2" do you mean? (the currently linked one seems to be relevant for your previous first question)

Answer (score 1):

Schema.org’s [`OpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification) can be used

- on its own,
- as value of [`ContactPoint`](http://schema.org/ContactPoint)’s [`hoursAvailable` property](http://schema.org/hoursAvailable), or
- as value of [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place)’s [`openingHoursSpecification` property](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification).

[`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) and [`Library`](http://schema.org/Library) are more-specific `Place` types, so **yes**, you can specify their opening hours by using the `openingHoursSpecification` property with a `OpeningHoursSpecification` value.

Comment: Hi UNOR, Thank you and I meant to refer to this http://schema.org/Store and if you scroll down then refer to the 2nd Example and then click on the tab named "Microdata".     

Thanks @Stephen Ostermiller