# Is having breadcrumb on a website enough to give result with bread crumb on google's SERP?

Tags: seo, microdata, search-results, breadcrumbs

Is having breadcrumb on a website enough to give result with bread crumb! on google's SERP?

[image]

I want to have this category : bread crumb in front of my url.

2 ways

1. go for micro data or schemas
2. leave it as it is, bcoz google will identify and catch it from your website breadcrumb and display it in my result - I find this the easiest one, but when it will happen and I am not sure this is the right choice considering the seo part in future.

I read this in comments somewhere, but I need in depth clarification.

You don't actually need any markup on breadcrumbs to make them appear in the SERPS. Simply having bread crumb navigation is enough to make them appear in the SERPS in my experience.

Comment: What you are asking is not quite clear. Can you give anonymous examples of what you are referring to? I understand bread-crumbs and mark-up but it sounds like you may be doing something different and I am not sure exactly where you are coming from. There are many here who can help you with this with a precise answer.

Comment: @closetnoc I have made some few changes. Please review it. sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience has been this.

Last year, Google scrambled to implement mark-up fully. Much of what Google suggested on it's site did not work or was not implemented and that frustrated early adopters. Google did a fantastic job of implementing mark-up and the work was done extremely fast. Today, it seems that mark-up works as advertised.

Prior to that, I found that bread-crumb style of links not using mark up could be picked up but not always fully understood- it would have to be simple. I had an unordered list of links that Google displayed but that may not have been intentional on Google's part.

Today I use the example I gave here: [Breadcrumb using Schema.org rich snippets](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32871/breadcrumb-using-and-schema-org-rich-snippets) and I cannot tell you if simple links still work. In fact, I should update how I use bread-crumbs based upon Google's examples.

I suggest using mark-up. Google does not guarantee that they will display bread-crumbs. This is unfortunate.

The theory behind using mark up to display bread-crumbs for Google was that the additional links increases the user experience and can satisfy the search users ability to find what they are looking for. I am not sure that is always the case. It depends upon the bread-crumbs. I found that even though almost 600,000 pages had bread-crumbs, Google would only display them for a number of the pages. The results were disappointing. This, for me, was not a problem since I did not create the bread-crumbs for Google but users.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, using Schema Breadcrumb data has always resulted in Google Site Links and categories (such as your picture).

Now this is not to say that this will always work for you, because I am sure that I have other factors that lead to this, but yes it is a key point I believe. I do also think this only happens if you have a fairly deep navigation - if your paths (URLs) are short, I don't think this will happen.

Google has some useful examples and data here: https://schema.org/breadcrumb