# Breadcrumb bug in Google results, using BreadcrumbList

Tags: google-search, microdata, rich-snippets, breadcrumbs, schema.org

I am using the Microdata format for my breadcrumbs as suggested by Google: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs

In Google SERPs it sometimes displays fine, but sometimes results in things like:

```
example.com › ... › Contact › Contact › Contact
```

While on the page the breadcrumb structure is:

```
Home › Contact
```

EDIT: Found out that this occurs in multiple places.

Comment: This seems a bit like the old joke- Doctor(!), it hurts when I do this... Doctor: Do not do that. Perhaps it is wise not to use the # for a navigational link. You may be confusing Google. I realize that you are using it as a placeholder. Try making it text based and not an actual link. That might work better.

Comment: :D I just found out that this thing also happens when I am not using #. The example above has fully functional URL-s in the breadcrumbs.

Comment: Question about same problem on Stack Overflow: [Schema.org's BreadcrumbList not displaying correctly in Google's search results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30755346/1591669)

Comment: Can you give us example code so that we can be absolutely sure we are giving you the straight skinny on this?? It sounds like there is a simple fundamental *thing* that can be changed to fix this. BTW- I found that breadcrumbs can be a bit touchy sometimes and is is not as helpful in the SERPs as people have said it is. I found that simplicity really helps here.

Comment: Here is an answer I gave a while ago: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32871/breadcrumb-using-schema-org-rich-snippets/58126#58126 Does this help?? This is the method I use, but have been removing some of them lately because I found that breadcrumbs really have not helped in the SERPs for CTR but can for user experience (UX) on the site itself.

Comment: @closetnoc I'll try your solution out right now. I just figured that the solution that Google itself recommends would work flawlessly. Clearly, this is not the case.

Comment: Things have changes since I wrote that answer. Google was busy at the time trying to implement mark-up and their own web site on the subject was pure garbage. They made fast and good work of implementing mark-up, but not without issues from time to time. Still, they did a very good job. I just noticed that at the time this seemed to be the most stable implementation and worked without issue. Hopefully, this is still the case.

Comment: @closetnoc I made the change yesterday and "Fetched the page as Googlebot" and submitted to index, but still the same behaviour under that SERP. Do you know how long it may take for the changes to appear in Google?

Comment: If you told it to *Index* after the *Fetch as Google* then it should revisit the page within about 4 hours. Indexing may take longer. I am a bit of a sneaky-pete- I would be putting something in the breadcrumbs that is unique that would get replaced but also does not look out of place and works for now. That way I will know when the change has taken place. BTW- I never saw the same problem you had with breadcrumbs. Hopefully this works. If not, it was worth a shot at least.

Comment: @closetnoc Good idea! I'll try that. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: It would really be helpful to have a URL :)

Comment: @JohnMueller https://likvidaator.com Strangely, my pages that are using the "official Google format" seem to have started appearing correctly under the SERP-s now, in the last 24 hours. Extremely confusing, but relieving at the same time.

Comment: @MarkusPint Thanks -- I'll pass that on to the team; on first glance that looks like something on Google's side.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I think this issue was resolved on Google's side quite some time ago.