# How to add categories snippet to search result

Tags: seo, google-search, rich-snippets, categories

There's that green structure link in search results, like seen below: 
[image]

When I'm looking at the HTML of that page, there's just a simple place at the bottom with categories:

```
<tbody>
<tr data-count="1" class=" ">
<td class='' ><span class=''><a href='/topsites/category/Computers/'>Computers</a> <span class='text-gt'>&gt;</span> <a href='/topsites/category/Computers/Hacking/'>Hacking</a> <span class='text-gt'>&gt;</span> <a href='/topsites/category/Computers/Hacking/Hardware/'>Hardware</a></span></td>                    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the eample page: http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/hackaday.com

How can I encourage Google to do the same for my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [breadcrumb snippet](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs) for that. Click on see markup data for example.

Below is breadcrumb I use it, in my own website.

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="/" itemprop="url"><span title="Goyllo" itemprop="title">Goyllo</span></a></span>
<span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">&#187; <a href="/seo/" itemprop="url"><span title="Search Engine Optimization" itemprop="title">Search Engine Optimization</span></a></span>
<span itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">&#187; <a href="/seo/basics/" itemprop="url"><span title="SEO Basics" itemprop="title">SEO Basics</span></a></span>
</div>
```

This will show snippet like this in serp

www.yoursite.com » Search Engine Optimization » SEO Basics

Data vocabulary is still supported by Google, I am still using it in my website from 2015 to 2017. Here is SS

[image]

Comment: Note that Data-Vocabulary.org (`Breadcrumb`) is no longer maintained (it might still work, though). The documentation you link to documents the use of Schema.org (`BreadcrumbList`).

Comment: @unor BreadcrumbList has [many](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82235/breadcrumb-bug-in-google-results-using-breadcrumblist) [bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755346/schema-orgs-breadcrumblist-not-displaying-correctly-in-googles-search-results) in past(2015), when I am trying to implement in my own website. Then I ready somewhere that data-vocabulary is working perfectly fine. I am still using it in 2017, and search console structure data tool also not show me any error from last 2 years :)